# Find $\lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(\frac{z+2-i}{3}\right)^\frac{z-i}{z-1-i}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am trying to find the limit

$$ \lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(\frac{z+2-i}{3}\right)^\frac{z-i}{z-1-i} $$

If we plug in $1+i$ for $z$, we get the following

$$ \lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(\frac{z+2-i}{3}\right)^\frac{z-i}{z-1-i}=1^\infty$$

Can we say that this limit equals to $1$?

Comment: Powers of complex numbers are not uniquely defined. You have to specify the branch you are using.

Comment: Aside from the comment above, $1^\infty$ is an indeterminate form, so you cannot make the claim. Consider $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/n)^n=e$ which is also of the form $1^\infty$.

Comment: This must not be the first $1^\infty$ limit you've ever seen. Remember how you dealt with other ones before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DeeponjitBose: please stop [abusing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) `\displaystyle`.

Comment: Let $z=x+(1+i)$ and work for $x \to 0$ to have a nice result (which is not $1$)

Comment: $1^\infty$ is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Letting $\omega=z-1-i$ converts the limit to
\begin{aligned}
L & =\lim _{\omega \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\omega+3}{3}\right)^{\frac{\omega+1}{\omega}} \\
& =\lim _{\omega \rightarrow 0}\left(1+\frac{\omega}{3}\right)^1\left(1+\frac{\omega}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{\omega}} \\
& =\left[\lim _{\omega \rightarrow 0}\left(1+\frac{\omega}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{\omega}}\right]^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
& =e^{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

While solving this question, one of the standard limits that must be kept in mind is as follows:

$\lim_{x\to0} (1+f(x))^{g(x)} \Longrightarrow e^{\lim_{x\to0} f(x).g(x)}$

On further evaluation:

$\lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(\frac{z+2-i}{3}\right)^\frac{z-i}{z-1-i}\\
\lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(1+\frac{z+2-i}{3}-1\right)^\frac{z-i}{z-1-i}\\
\lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(1+\frac{z-1-i}{3}\right)^\frac{z-i}{z-1-i}\\
e^{\lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(\frac{z-1-i}{3}\right).\left(\frac{z-i}{z-1-i}\right)}\\
e^{\lim_{z\to 1+i}\left(\frac{z-i}{3}\right)}\\
e^{\frac{1+i-i}{3}}\\
e^{\frac{1}{3}}$

So, $e^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is your final answer. Thank you!